# Exif data not enought info for geo location

Tags: python, geolocation, exif

I am trying to get geo location from image, to show where does it taken.
I am using exifread libriary and this function:

```
def info(image):
    f = open(image, 'rb')
    tags = dict(exifread.process_file(f))
    for tag in tags.keys():
        if "GPS" in tag:
            print "Key: %s, value %s" % (tag, tags[tag])
    return
```

It returns me this info:

```
Key: GPS GPSLatitudeRef, value N
Key: GPS GPSLatitude, value [42, 51, 28]
Key: GPS GPSProcessingMethod, value [65, 83, 67, 73, 73, 0, 0, 0, 71, 80, 83]
Key: GPS GPSDate, value 2015:08:18
Key: GPS GPSVersionID, value [2, 2, 0, 0]
Key: Image GPSInfo, value 722
Key: GPS GPSAltitudeRef, value 0
Key: GPS GPSTimeStamp, value [17, 42, 7]
Key: GPS GPSLongitude, value [74, 19, 35]
Key: GPS GPSLongitudeRef, value E
Key: GPS GPSAltitude, value 694
```

I use GPSLatitude(42.5128) and GPSLongitude(74.1935), as coordinates, but accuracy is very low, because there is only 4 numbers after comma.
What should I do to get more accurate results?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the location was determined with consumer-level (non-military) gear without some other sort of correction, 4 decimal places is as accurate as you're going to be able to get.

Some useful links:

- [What is the maximum Theoretical accuracy of GPS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43617/what-is-the-maximum-theoretical-accuracy-of-gps)
- [Good coverage of accuracy/precision in GPS measurements](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude)
- [Official US Government page on GPS accuracy](http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/)

Comment: Photo taken with good accuracy, about 5 meters. And location determinated well on some online resourses. Thanks for links.

Answer (score 0):

Exif stores latitude/longitude data using rational numbers. i.e. `A/B`. The library you're using is converting them to HMS for you, and possibly losing some information. Check whether that's the case by running the image through another Exif viewer, ideally reading the raw rational values. You can then find out whether the image's metadata has more precision than you are getting from exifread.